# Limit of sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Sequence $(x_{n})$ is such that $x_{k} \in (0, 1)$ for all $k \in N$ with    $x_{n+1} < \cfrac{x_{n} + x_{n-1}}{2}$. Is this sequence convergent, if so find its set of limits.

Comment: Can you show us your try?

Answer (score 0):

For some $l\in [0,1)$ define $$a_n=ke^{-n}+l$$for some small enough $k>0$ such that $a_n\in (0,1)$. Therefore $$a_{n+1}=ke^{-n-1}+l=l+{k\over e}e^{-n}\\{a_n+a_{n-1}\over 2}=l+k{e^{-n}+e^{-n+1}\over 2}=l+k\cdot {1+e^{-1}\over 2}e^{-n}$$from $${1\over e}<{1+{1\over e}\over 2}$$we conclude that $a_{n+1}<{a_n+a_{n-1}\over 2}$ which shows that some $a_n$ exists to tend to $l$ and therefore all $l\in[0,1)$ are achievable. To show that $1$ is not achievable, note that if for some $0<M<1$, $a_{n-1},a_n\le M$ then $a_{n+1}\le M$ for all $n$. Since such an $M$ exists for every $a_n$, then neither of them can tend to $1$ and the limit-set is $[0,1)$.